# Redirection for specific string in obj.conf

Tags: oracle, webserver, redirect, iplanet

I have made URL redirection in obj.conf file of Oracle iPlanet WebServer.

The server domain is https://www.example.com

Entry in obj.conf
`NameTrans fn="redirect" from="/Test/p" url=https://www.example01.com/myredirection.html`

So when I am hitting https://www.example.com/Test/p , it is redirecting to https://www.example01.com/myredirection.html. Which is well and good. But in my "Test" folder, 
there are some html pages starting with "p", and for those also redirection is happening.

Like https://www.example.com/Test/pDemo.html is also redirecting to https://www.example01.com/myredirection.html. (which i don't want)

I want when user types https://www.example.com/Test/p , only then redirection should happen. Could u please suggest.